# How to run pytest file by file in no particular order

Tags: python, flask, pytest, coverage.py

I am testing a backend of Flask and MongoDB but run into a problem when running the total test suite. If I run certain files in the test suite independently, they work fine. I wrote a script which runs each file alone but this gives me problems since the coverage report only takes the last test.

**Is there a way to run each file independently with one command? Or is there a way to aggregate all the tests into one coverage report?**

Unfortunately I am not able to share the code but will give as much information as I can. Thank you very much for any help.

**Addition**
When running the tests from the top level, it initiates with the line

`**collecting ... ** Testing database connected Database(MongoClient(host=['localhost:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=False), 'TESTS')`

This line is not present when running the file individually.

Comment: Go to the top level folder and just run with `pytest` command.

Comment: @DevangSanghani thank you. When I do this certain tests fail and so the report doesn't seem to include them.

Comment: Then perhaps need to fix them?

Comment: Ideally failed tests should also come in the report.

Comment: @DevangSanghani yeah that's what I think too but it doesn't seem as though they are

Comment: @DevangSanghani have added an edit which might help